# Struct char array member initialization in C++

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I'm trying to understand struct initialization in C++, in special char array member:

```
struct S {
    int x;
    char str[16];
};

// (1) This would be the desired way: simple and compact, but doesn't work
S s1={.x=12, .str = "Hello2"};

// (2) Instead, this appears the correct way to do, but it is ugly and cumbersome for bigger strings
S s2={.x=25, .str = {'H','e','l','l','o', '1'}};

// (3) This works too, easy to type, but uses 2 lines and a additional function (strcpy)
S s3={.x=12};
strcpy(s3.str, "Hello3");
```

Why doesn't modern C ++ accept the (1) form? It would be the most elegant, concise and practical way.
Considering (2) and (3), is there a better way to do this?

EDIT 1: The code I choose to put in this question has been oversimplified. My actual code involves a char[] member within a union within a structure. Then, **std::string is not an option**.

Comment: any reason why `str` is not a `std::string`?

Comment: The standard way to handle strings in C++ is to use `std::string`. What is the actual problem this structure is supposed to solve? Why do you need a fixed-size array? And if you can't get rid of the array, why not create a constructor which initializes the array?

Comment: "Why doesn't modern C ++ accept the (1) form?" Because modern C++ (and old C++) uses `std::string` instead of char arrays.

Comment: Your (1) code *does* work in `clang-cl` and `MSVC` (the latter with `/std:c++latest` - in order to use the designated initializers).

Comment: The code I chose to put in this question has been oversimplified. My actual code involves a char[] member within a union within a structure. I can't put std::string inside union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace

> ```
> S s1={.x=12, .str = "Hello2"};
> ```

by the 'C' initialization form

```
S s1={12, "Hello2"};
```

or as said in remarks use a `std::string` which is a most elegant, concise and practical way than an array of char for a string, and you will able to use the 'C++' initialization form you wanted

Comment: But It requires to follow the order of the member fields. It is  possible to use designators (member names) in some way?

Comment: @Berk7871 yes you have to take care of the order as in C, no you cannot use designators because only the C++ form allows that

Comment: Ok. I am curious as to why the C ++ Committee did not include this simple feature (allowing the use of designators to initialize a char[] from a literal string) in the language.